# Shared scope variable is not updating across directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having a strange issue with directive, I am trying to create the plunkr, but before that posting this to SO, to see if I get any response.

I have a following variable in controller:

```
$scope.sharedVar = [];
$scope.loopIs = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];
```

Now I am passing this variable to direective through ng-repeat:

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="val in loopIs">
  <my-directive val="val" sharedVar="sharedVar"></my-directive>
</div>
```

And Here is my directive:

```
app.directive(myDirective){
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    val: '=val',
    sharedVar: '=sharedVar'
   },
   templateUrl: 'template.html',
   link: function(scope){
      //...........My logic here
   }
  }
}
```

sharedVar is shared across directives, so I want this to get updated if it changes from any directive.

Can any one please help me here. Am I doing anything wrong with directive inside ng-repeat?

========update========

i have added the plunkr.. please have a look.

https://plnkr.co/edit/lhE3UwjJzqNgk2jd8BIV?p=preview

Comment: I think you will not be able to run your code with `app.directive(myDirective){` syntax.

Comment: Please ignore that.. thats because i just gave a sample

Comment: I have added the plunkr

Comment: it's working fine in your plunkr

Comment: sharedVar is shared across directive, so it should update everywhere, if it changes through any directive.. Hope u understood my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$parent` as *ng-repeat* create separate scope itself

```
 <my-directive val="val" shared-var="$parent.sharedVar"></my-directive>
```

[Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/FlOK5NJ1ioCF6dcwQscm?p=preview)

Comment: You are awesome.. First time I used  $parent. It worked like charm. You saved so many hours of mine. Thanks MUCH

Comment: glad to know it helped you.